# MySQLi CURDATE() today and 2 hours in to tomorrow?

Tags: php, mysql, date

I am retrieving results from my database using the current date.

My current code looks like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * 
        FROM `1ymzj0g_orders` 
        WHERE `processed` = '1' 
         AND DATE(`order_date`) = CURDATE() LIMIT 100";
```

This is great for getting results from TODAY although for my circumstances, it needs to get the results from today and up to 2am tomorrow morning.

I am guessing under the current layout after midnight my results will clear, however I need to keep the results after midnight, but not for two whole days, just up to about 2am.

Is this possible? And if so could you provide me with some advice here?

Comment: What should this do during a Daylight Saving Time switch? Just two hours into the next day, or three, or one?

Comment: Oh wow, I haven't even thought that far ahead... I'm guessing still limit to 2am as I can't imagine the shop staying open until 3am. I can always configure it if needs be.

Comment: What I mean is 2am is either 1, 2, or 3 hours after midnight depending on the day of the year. Something to keep in mind. The time you've picked here is coincidentally within the one hour window when DST kicks in.

Comment: Although there isn't a problem if the results show until say 4am, 6am or whatever. As long as they don't show for the next shift starting at around midday.

Comment: I'd probably stick to the safe side and say 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use DATE_ADD with an HOUR interval to set a limit on the order_date 
some thing similar to this :

```
WHERE DATE(`order_date`) = CURDATE() OR DATE(`order_date`) < DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL + 12 HOUR)
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be -2 HOUR rather than -12?

Comment: `DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL + 26 HOUR)` (up to 2am tomorrow)

Comment: So if I add `+ 26 hour` it will give me all results from today and after midnight tonight display todays results as well until 2am?

Comment: yes also depending on your data retention , you might need to add also after the OR a DATE(`order_date`) > CURDATE()

Comment: Obviously I cannot test it accurately until about 1am this morning, although I've modified it slightly to: `(DATE(`order_date`) = CURDATE() OR DATE(`order_date`) > DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL - 12 HOUR))` seeing as the results still shown when changing the date to about a week ago or so? Does this look correct?

Comment: if you run this at 1 am INTERVAL - 12  , will give you since yesterday at 12 noon.  is this what you want?